# Extract and process linenumber from grep due to an error in windows (because the extracted number is a string)

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I have a problem with extracted linenumbers from a grep result.
Windows (gitBash) can't compare them, because the number is a string and not a number (my macOS does it without problems).

```
What i want to do is: add a leading zero to the line numbers if they are smaller than 10
```

Here is the code snippet:

   `local number=""
   local command=""
   # grep complete list and itereate over this list
   grep -n --color=always "${1}" "${2}" | while read -r greppedList ; do
      for ln in "${greppedList}" ; do
         # split the line to number and command
         number=$(echo ${ln} | cut -d ':' -f 1)
         if (( ${number} < 10 )) ; then
            command="${ln:2:${#ln}-1}"
         else
            command="${ln:3:${#ln}-1}"
         fi
         printWithFormattedLineNumbers "${number}" "${command}"
      done
   done`


The problem on windows is that line `if (( ${number} < 10 )) ; then`.
windows can't compare it because it is not number.

Can you help me changing the way to get the linenumber?

Comment: I don't know if it will work in Windows, but you could try this `while IFS=':' read num line;do printf 'number %02d - line %s\n' $num "$line";done`.

Comment: i had problems with `while IFS=':' read num line`, that didn't work if there was only one line. But the most important fact was `%02d - line %s\n' $num "$line"` - that works perfectly. **Thank you!**

Comment: If passing IFS to `read` didn't  work, try doing the cut directly as printf arguments `grep -n --color=always "${1}" "${2}" | while read -r greppedList ; do  printf 'number %02d - line %s\n' "$(cut -d':' -f1 <<<"$greppedList")" "$(cut -d':' -f2- <<<"$greppedList")" ; done`. I think the `printf` line replaces the `for` loop.

Comment: yes that also works, but is a very long line :D **thanky you for your help!**

Comment: you can find on github https://github.com/m1well/cheatsheet at the script on line 261 an 270 your code now ;)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem on windows is that line if (( ${number} < 10 )) ; then.
>   windows can't compare it because it is not number.

Then treat it as a character string, and use a `case` statement instead of `if`:

```
case "${number}" in
[0-9])
        command="${ln:2:${#ln}-1}"
        ;;
*)
        command="${ln:3:${#ln}-1}"
esac
```